# Express backend receives [Object: null prototype] {} from req.cookies

Tags: express, cookies, gatsby

I am using Gatsby for my front end and Express for my backend. Despite what I have tried, I receive a null object back for my cookies. I have made sure to include the credentials option for fetch, but I am still running into the same issue.

This is my code for index.js on the backend

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:8000', credentials: true}))

app.use(express.json())

app.get('/hi', (req, res)=> {
    console.log('Here be cookies', req.cookies)

    res.status(200).json({message: 'hello there'})
})

app.post('/hello', (req, res)=> {
    const {text} = req.body

    res.cookie('the_cookie', 'NOMNOMNOM', {
        path: '/',
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'lax',
        expiresIn: Date.now() + 1000 * 3600
    })

    res.status(200).json({message: text})
})

app.listen(3001, ()=> {
    console.log('app is listening on port 3001')
})
```

Part of My index.js for Gatsby, when the button on the page is clicked, the cookie will be created

```
import * as React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"



const IndexPage = () => {
  async function sendRequest() {
    await fetch( 'http://localhost:3001/hello', {
      method: "POST",
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }, 
      "body": JSON.stringify({text: 'This is the way'})
  }).then((res)=> {
      console.log(res)
      return res.json() 
  }).catch(err => console.log(err)) 
   
  }
```

ssr.js - when this page is loaded, the GET request is called, and the backend will attempt to retrieve the cookie

```
import * as React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

const SSRPage = ({ serverData }) => (
  <main>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    {serverData.message}
  </main>
)


export default SSRPage

export async function getServerData() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/hi`, {
      method: "GET",
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }})
   
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Response failed`)
    }

    return {
      props: await res.json(),
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      status: 500,
      headers: {},
      props: {}
    }
  }
}
```

My routes work, but I am unable to retrieve the cookie object after it is created. The full version of the app is attempting to retrieve a saved http-only cookie, but receives a null object. The cookie retrieval is successful when using Postman, but empty when running in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: How are `/hi` and `/hello` related?

Comment: When the /hello route receives a post request from the front end, it creates the cookie, and when the /hi route receives a get request, it attempts to retrieve the cookie